# Selecting a UITableViewCell in Edit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview

If I create a UITableViewController - drilling down works as expected. If a user selects a cell and I implement 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath', the cell flashes blue and the next view shows up.

But, if I include an 'edit' button (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem), when the user clicks 'Edit' - the mode correctly changes (all the cells indent and paint an appropriate editingAccessory), ... BUT, the cells are no long 'selectable'.

IE: while in edit mode, when a user selects a cell, nothing is happening. No blue flash. No invocation of 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath', nothing.

When I open the iPhone example 'iPhoneCoreDataRecipes' (as provided in the SDK docs), sure enough, they have a RecipeDetailViewController - that, when put into edit mode, still allows you to drill down. I've downloaded and built their example and it works just fine. I can't seem to find any trickery in their code to enable this 'selectable cell when in edit mode behavior' but I'm just not getting it when I do it.

Thoughts?

Thanks for any time,

-Luther

Answer (score 64, accepted):

UITableView has a property [allowsSelectionDuringEditing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsSelectionDuringEditing) for this.

IMHO it should have been YES by default.

Comment: You may have missed it in the sample code you spoke of, because it can also be set in Interface Builder.

Comment: i am a newbie on this, so could you provide a sample code example?

Comment: In Interface builder its not set to YES by default.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the [allowsSelectionDuringEditing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsSelectionDuringEditing) property of `UITableView` to `YES`.

The default value is `NO`.

Answer (score 3):

It can be changed in Storyboard:

[image]